# MongoDB aggregation - Group by _id and then prioritize by another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I've been stuck on this for about 5 days.

I'm trying to aggregate an array of MongoDB objects that look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 2,
    store: "Vincenzo Pizza Tavern",
    bundle: "",
    group: "",
    state: "nothing",
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    store: "Vincenzo Pizza Tavern",
    bundle: "VinnyBundle",
    group: "VinnyGroup",
    state: "waiting",
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    store: "Marios",
    bundle: "",
    group: "Mario Group",
    state: "nothing",
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    store: "Marios",
    bundle: "Mias_Dias",
    group: "Mario Group",
    state: "waiting",
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    store: "Marios",
    bundle: "Mias_Dias_Menu",
    group: "Mario Group",
    state: "current",
  }
]
```

The data must be grouped on _id and also prioritize the state field. The order of priority is "nothing", "waiting" and "current".

```
Outcome:

[
  {
    _id: 2,
    store: "Vincenzo Pizza Tavern",
    bundle: "VinnyBundle",
    group: "VinnyGroup",
    state: "waiting",
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    store: "Marios",
    bundle: "Mias_Dias_Menu",
    group: "Mario Group",
    state: "current",
  }
]
```

Comment: is your output correct?

Comment: The `_id` must be unique and look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4xaJjtySjO2)

Comment: Thanks @turivishal. I think this actually solves my issue but based on the question the below answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The data must be grouped on _id and also prioritize the state field. The order of priority is "nothing", "waiting" and "current".

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M2paPTXkkLR)

As pointed out in the comments

1. `_id` has to be unique
2. Your expected outcome is different than description

To achieve what you need as mentioned in the statements

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { //custom sort order
      type: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$state",
              "nothing"
            ]
          },
          0,
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$state",
                  "waiting"
                ]
              },
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {//sort
      "type": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {//group by `id` - a custom field than `_id`
      "_id": "$id",
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```